# How to select in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html and need to grab the price to a variable when the button is clicked using jQuery. Ideally just want the number without the £ sign.

```
<p><span class="gift_price">£12.99</span></p>                                                                       

<form><input type="submit" value="Add to basket" class="add_to_basket" /></form>
```

I have the following but can't quite get any further:

```
 $(".add_to_basket").click(function(){
                    var price = $(this).parent().prev()[0];
                    return false;
                });
```

But this only gets me as far as the `<p> ... </p>`

There are lots of these on a page so can't just select by .gift_price, need to do it by getting the closest one to the submit button

I'm sure there is a super quick way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `var price = $(this).parent().prev()[0];`, as you point out, is selecting the `<p>` rather than the desired `<span>` inside of that. That's because `prev()` returns a jQuery object, and the `0` property is the HTML element that corresponds to it, not the child element of the `<p>`. So just change the `[0]` for `.children()`:

```
var price = $(this).parent().prev().children();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: **DOSN'T WORK!** *(it was just a quick idea)*

```
            $(".add_to_basket").click(function(){
                var price = $(this).parent().closest(".gift_price")[0];
                return false;
            });
```

Or you can use the `find` method:

```
var price = $(this).parent().prev().find(".gift_price")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely, if you have the p parents - you just need the [child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)?:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children("span:first")
```

Comment: The name is `children()` and it selects all `P` children. But again `children()[0]` will return the first child as DOM element. In your case `span.gift_price`

Comment: .child() is not a method. you mean .children()

Comment: @maxedison Sorry, children is correct - possibly using :first or [0] - FGIW typo

Comment: @AndreasAL yes children() - sorry, typo caused by rushing.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change things just a bit...

```
<ul>
  <li>...other items...</li>
  <li>
    <p><span class="gift_price">£12.99</span></p>
    <form><input type="submit" value="Add to basket" class="add_to_basket" /></form>
  </li>
  <li>...other items...</li>
</ul>
```

And then for javascript...

```
var price = $(this).closest('li').find(".gift_price")[0];
```

It gives it a bit more semantic meaning and helps you find the correct item w/o worrying about changing your html later.

Answer (score 0):

It would be even cleaner if you simply identified the span with an id.

**HTML**

```
<p><span id="mygiftprice" class="gift_price">£12.99</span></p>                                                                       

<form><input type="submit" value="Add to basket" class="add_to_basket" /></form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".add_to_basket").click(function(){
  var price = $('#mygiftprice').text().replace("£", "");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like it may work for you:

```
$(".add_to_basket").click(function(){
    var price = $(this).children('.gift_price')[0];
    var priceWithoutCurrency = price.replace(/\£/g, '')
    return false;
});
```

More info found at: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/